# ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration "because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher, configurationmanager

I'd like to re-read the MySolution.main.config (my app.config) thanks FileSystemWatcher when users modify it. I built a wrapper called FileWatcher.

Catching OnChanged event with this piece of code

```
    var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = _appConfigFilePath };
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

raises this exception

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException   HResult=0x80131902
> Message=An error occurred loading a configuration file: The process
> cannot access the file
> 'C:\Source\Solutions\MySolution_1.2.3\MySolution\bin\Debug\MySolution.main.config'
> because it is being used by another process.
> (C:\Source\Solutions\MySolution_1.2.3\MySolution\bin\Debug\MySolution.main.config)
> Source=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager   StackTrace:    at
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean
> ignoreLocal) in
> /*/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ConfigurationSchemaErrors.cs:line
> 71    at
> System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors
> schemaErrors) in
> /*/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/BaseConfigurationRecord.cs:line
> 3634    at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor(String
> locationSubPath, Type typeConfigHost, Object[]
> hostInitConfigurationParams) in
> /*/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/Configuration.cs:line
> 75    at
> System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationFileMap
> fileMap, Boolean isMachine, ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, String
> exePath) in
> /*/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ClientConfigurationHost.cs:line
> 485    at
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationImpl(ConfigurationFileMap
> fileMap, Boolean isMachine, ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, String
> exePath, Boolean preLoad) in
> /*/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:line
> 214    at
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(ExeConfigurationFileMap
> fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel) in
> /*/src/libraries/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.cs:line
> 192    at
> Siav.MySolution.Log.ConfigurationUtil.FileWatcher.OnChanged(Object
> sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) in
> C:\Source\Solutions\MySolution_1.2.3\Siav.MySolution.Log\ConfigurationUtil\FileWatcher.cs:line
> 60    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnChanged(FileSystemEventArgs e)
> in f:\dd\NDP\fx\src\services\io\system\io\FileSystemWatcher.cs:line
> 822    at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32
> action, String name) in
> f:\dd\NDP\fx\src\services\io\system\io\FileSystemWatcher.cs:line 773
> at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32
> errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer) in
> f:\dd\NDP\fx\src\services\io\system\io\FileSystemWatcher.cs:line 594
> at
> System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
> errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) in
> f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\overlapped.cs:line 121
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int, string) in __error.cs
> System.IO.FileStream.Init(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, int, bool, System.IO.FileShare, int,
> System.IO.FileOptions,
> Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, string, bool, bool,
> bool) in filestream.cs
> System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(string, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare) in filestream.cs
> System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticOpenStreamForRead(string)
> in InternalConfigHost.cs
> System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(string)
> in InternalConfigHost.cs
> System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.OpenStreamForRead(string)
> in ClientConfigurationHost.cs
> System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(string) in UpdateConfigHost.cs
> System.Configuration.ImplicitMachineConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(string)
> in ImplicitMachineConfigHost.cs
> System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile() in BaseConfigurationRecord.cs
>
> Inner Exception 1: IOException: The process cannot access the file
> 'C:\Source\Solutions\MySolution_1.2.3\MySolution\bin\Debug\MySolution.main.config'
> because it is being used by another process.

I tried with a simple lock, it doesn't work.

This is the constructor of my wrapper

```
    public FileWatcher(string appConfigFilePath)
    {
        _appConfigFilePath = appConfigFilePath;


        _lastRead = DateTime.MinValue;

        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Path.GetDirectoryName(_appConfigFilePath))
        {
            Filter = Path.GetFileName(_appConfigFilePath),
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,

            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        watcher.Error += OnError;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is entirely normal when you use FileSystemWatcher, the class is *very* efficient at generating the event.  Which is raised when the process that modified the .config file is still busy writing it.  You have to try later, many existing questions about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manage some retry to access the file as log4net does. I suggest to you to do the same (log4net source is available on github)